# Extending Array with custom method that removes an element by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods, prototype

I have to make a new array method, that when called it removes a specific 'value' from an array. It works with numbers, but when I use a string it returns an empty array...

```js
Array.prototype.removeItem = function(value){
 for(var key in this){
 this.splice(this.indexOf(value), 1);
 }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, '1'];
console.log(arr);
arr.removeItem(1);
console.log(arr);

var arrSecond = ['hi', 'bye', 'hello' ];
console.log(arrSecond);
arrSecond.removeItem('hi');
console.log(arrSecond);
```

Comment: I really don't see it working with numbers… `[2, 4, 3, 4, 111]` (the result that I get) is lacking the `3` and the `'1'`.

Comment: Your iteration is reducing the array constantly because of the `indexOf()` method.

Comment: splicing in a loop like that is bad news

Comment: Why are you iterating at all given that you are using *indexOf*? And *for..in* on arrays is not recommended when there is *forEach*, *map*, *reduce*, *filter*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *value* isn't found, *indexOf* will return -1. A negative start passed to *splice* is counted from the end. See [*ECMA-262 §15.4.4.14*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14)

So once you remove the value from the array, after that you are removing the last member.

A better method might be something like:

```
var index;
while ((index = this.indexOf(value)) > -1) {
  this.splice(index, 1);
}
```

*for..in* should not be used here, consider *forEach* for Array loops instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new and I'm sorry, that I do such stupid mistakes, but I'm learning. You give a helping hand for everyone in need, so thank you again! Thank you and everyone else, that commented above...